# Fetching pdf file from MediaStore shows the list of data that doesnt even exist in internal storage and sd card

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-storage

I want to know how can i use mediastore to check whether the file that i am fetching from my storage is deleted or present in my storage.The problem that i am facing is my pdf app is showing the deleted pdf which were deleted maybe 2-4 months earlier.I am sharing my code please let me know how to solve this issue.

Here is my code:

```
  protected ArrayList<String> getPdfList() {
ArrayList<String> pdfList = new ArrayList<>();
Uri collection;

final String[] projection = new String[]{
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
};

final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

final String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?";

final String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{mimeType};

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
}else{
    collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
}


try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(collection, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)) {
    assert cursor != null;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int columnData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
        int columnName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        do {
            pdfList.add((cursor.getString(columnData)));
            Log.d(TAG, "getPdf: " + cursor.getString(columnData));
            //you can get your pdf files
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
return pdfList;
}
```

Comment: `whether the file that i am fetching from my storage is deleted or present in my storage.` I think that if you can fetch a file from your storage its present in your storage. Please edit your post to better tell the scenario.

Comment: Start with the path or uri you use to display the file.

Comment: no they are not present in my storage but i get to know that even after deleting file from storage they remain in mediastorage.So my question is how do i know that whether the file in media storage is deleted one(not existing in storage) or existing one.

Comment: I asked you to edit your post. Write a better post to begin with. Change the subject too as you are just listing pdf files using the media store.